# Android Studio Emulator stopped working after installing Windows Subsystem for Android on Windows 11

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I have installed Windows Subsystem for Android and I am able to run apps on windows 11 however when I tried to run the emulator I created on Android Studio, it just does not no longer work and Android emulator is not responding.

It was working prior to the install, so I am assuming the cause could be when I installed WSA

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on/off the Hyper-V option which you will get in the programs and features tab in control panel.

Answer (score 0):

These are the four solution might help you to solve your problem.
This error occurs after installing latest android studio with amd processor.

1. Turning on/off SVM Mode will solve.
2. Install HAXM again
3. Turn on/off Hyper-V
4. AMD processor most of time shows this type of errors.